# Mix two scatterplots in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, scatter-plot

I would like to mix two scatterplots in just one, with different colours to each of them for comparasion.

codes used to obtains the two scatterplots:

```
 plot(allsize, allfreq)

 plot(allsize2, allfreq2)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Change the second line to `points(allsize2, allfreq2, col="red")` and add a col parameter to the first plot, if you want to choose that colour also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot(allsize, allfreq, col = "blue")
plot(allsize2, allfreq2, col = "red", add = TRUE)
```